# Is there a difference between window.onload = stuff and window.onload = stuff()?

Tags: javascript

I'm most familiar with Python and somewhat with C, and when I see this syntax in JS it really confuses me

```
function begin () {
    console.log("done did it");
}

window.onload = begin(); // the same output as
window.onload = begin;   // this one
```

In Python, one would be passing the return value of the function, the other a pointer to the function. What are the semantics in JS for these two statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's a very big difference.

`window.onload = stuff();` will *call* the `stuff` function and assign its return value to the `onload` property.

`window.onload = stuff;` assigns the `stuff` function to the property `onload`. The browser will call that function when the `load` event occurs. Functions are objects. When you refer to them by their name *without* calling them, you're referring to the object. This would be similar to the "function pointer" you were talking about.

Comment: So you're saying, that the behaviour is the same as with Python?

Comment: @MorganWilde: I don't know Python well enough to say that, but from what you've described, I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is :

```
window.onload = xxxx;
```

the xxx must be a function.

the first one:

```
var fn = function() {
    alert("abc");
}

window.onload = fn;
```

the other one:

```
var fn = function() {
    var abc = "abc";
    return function () {
        alert(abc);
    }
}
window.onload = fn();
```